# Varnish VCL not allowing two separate IP addresses as backends

Tags: apache-2.2, varnish

Every time I attempt to add an extra back end into our VCL file, it's fails.

Here is the DAEMON_OPTS we are running off:

DAEMON_OPTS="-a :80 \
             -T localhost:6082 \
             -f /etc/varnish/custom.vcl \
             -u varnish -g varnish \
             -S /etc/varnish/secret \
             -s malloc,10G"

And here is the offending backend(s)

backend b1 {
  .host = "114.123.456.789";
  .port = "8080";
}

backend b2 {
  .host = "203.123.456.789";
  .port = "80";
}

Any Ideas ? Gut feeling is it might need the backends to be set somewhere, but I'm not sure where.

**Solved**

So, it turns out I needed to set the backends in the vcl script, further down in the vcl file (vcl_recv). If this helps anyone else, this is the code that I copied from (https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/VCLExampleRestarts)

```
sub vcl_recv {
            if (req.restarts == 0) {
                    set req.backend = b1;
            } else if (req.restarts == 1) {
                    set req.backend = b2;
            }
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what the failure looks like?  Does Varnish start with the problem config in place, or fail to start?  If it's failing, what's logged?

Comment: Varnish is failing to start at all. Have to revert back to a vcl with one backend to get it to restart.

I'll see if there's anything in the logs now.

Comment: Actually, the best place to look for errors during start is the binary's output.  Your init script is probably sending stdout and stderr to `/dev/null` - temporarily tweak that to allow that output to be displayed, then try to start the service again?

Comment: looked into varnish's own logs and /var/messages and couldn't find anything out the the ordinary.

Comment: Right, you need to look at the output from the service start, not the logs.  See my previous message.

Answer (score 1):

So, it turns out I needed to set the backends in the vcl script, further down. If this helps anyone else, this is the code that I copied from (https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/VCLExampleRestarts)

```
sub vcl_recv {
            if (req.restarts == 0) {
                    set req.backend = b1;
            } else if (req.restarts == 1) {
                    set req.backend = b2;
            } else {
                    set req.backend = b3;
            }
}
```

Bizarre, but true